# Como permitir caracteres especiais em Python?

Tags: python, ascii, caracteres

No meu programa eu quero incluir caracteres como estes no print:
╣, ╠, ╬, e mais alguns deste tipo.
Estou tentando pegar uma matriz com números e transformá-los nestes caracteres, de forma que pareça um mapa/labirinto.

Obs: quero que uma posição [x][y] da matriz receba este caracter como conteúdo.

```
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        if matriz[i][j] == 0:
            sqm[i][j] = " "
        elif matriz[i][j] == 1:
            sqm[i][j] = "0"
        elif matriz[i][j] == 2:
            sqm[i][j] = u("U+25AC")
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        print sqm[i][j],
    print ""
```

Desta forma precisa já estar incluso dentro da matriz.

No começo do código ja uso:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Mas só cobre acentuação.
Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 1):

Para isso é só procurar os caracteres unicode que voce dejesa "printar" e utilizar o comando:

```
print(u'\u2551')
║
```

Exemplo:

```
box = [u'\u2550',u'\u2551',u'\u2552',u'\u2553',u'\u2554',u'\u2555',u'\u2556',
u'\u2557',u'\u2558',u'\u2559',u'\u225A']

print(box)
['═', '║', '╒', '╓', '╔', '╕', '╖', '╗', '╘', '╙', '≚']
```

Voce pode ver a tabela completa dos caracteres chamados de "box drawing" [nesse link.](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2500.pdf), ou se precisar (e tiver paciencia) pode verificar [todas as tabelas unicode, aqui.](http://www.unicode.org/charts)

[Execute o código no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JtGL/1)

> **Editada:**
>   Depois que o autor da pergunta a editou e colocou o código.

Observando o código, da para perceber o erro exatamente onde o objetivo é atribuir o caracter à posição da matriz: `sqm[i][j] = u("U+25AC")`, provavelmente essa 'notação' deve ter sido deduzida [dessa tabela](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Geometric_Shapes), ou alguma semelhante. Mas quando a tabela apresenta `U+25AC`, a conversão para o python deve se tornar `u'\u25ac'`, então, é só trocar a linha:

```
sqm[i][j] = u("U+25AC")
```

Por:

```
sqm[i][j] = u'\u25ac'
```

[Veja esse caracter acrescentado à tabela na nova versão, no repl.it.](https://repl.it/JtGL/2)

Answer (score 0):

Olá, você pode tentar achar o código dos caracteres que você precisar aqui https://unicode-table.com/pt/#ipa-extensions e assim fazer o seguinte:

Por exemplo para o caractere '©' em python 2:

```
print u"\u00a9"
```

resultado:

©

ou em python 3:

```
print("\u00a9")
```

resultado:

©

Comment: Acho que não expliquei direito, mas vou consertar.
Quero que este caracter seja incluído dentro da matriz pq eu imprimo caracter por caracter da matriz na tela.
Ai seria incluido em alguma posição [x][y], e não apenas impresso na tela